# Passing an array and an object from a Controller to a View in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been trying to get the CodeIgniter view to work with passing an object and an array at the same time, however it seems to break when I add the object.

Generally in CodeIgniter, when you create a variable in the Controller:`$data['title'] = 'Welcome to CodeIgniter'`, you would access that variable in the View as: `$title`,

I need to pass my userdata which I retrieve by:

```
$data['title'] = 'welcome to codeigniter';
$this-db->where('id', $id);
$user = $this->db->get('users')->row();

$this->load->view('welcome', [
    'data' => $data,
    'user' => $user
]);
```

However, when I get to my view, `$active` is undefined, and I have to access the it by `$data['title']`

I have also tried adding everything to one array:

```
$data = array(
     'title' => 'welcome to codeigniter',
    'active' => 'home', 
     'user' => $user,
);
```

However, it did not work.

If this doesn't make sense I apologize, I am trying to explain my issue as best as I can, if you need further information, please let me know.

Thanks,
Moonblaze

Comment: In your first example, you have not defined $active in your view array so that is expected. In your 2nd example, what is "it did not work" actually look like?

Comment: My apologies, I ment to type `$title`, not `$active`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
$data['title'] = 'welcome to codeigniter';
$this-db->where('id', $id);
$data['user'] = $this->db->get('users')->row();
$this->load->view('welcome', $data );
```

In view you can access like:

```
echo $title; //will print the 'welcome to codeigniter'
print_r($user); // will hold the resource of query
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$data['title'] = 'welcome to codeigniter';
$this-db->where('id', $id);
$user = $this->db->get('users')->row();
$data[user]=$user;
$this->load->view('welcome', $data );
```

You can use $title and $user in your view

Comment: This wouldn't work, as I am almost sure php would try and process the `[data]` and `[user]` as constants... I tried it just to double check, and yeah it did.

Comment: yes , use can use $data variable onlu istead id $data_new  . but it will also work (no recommended) as the answer by @Suresh Kamrushi is most efficient .

Comment: I see where you were going with this, it's very similar with the now accepted answer, however you would need to change `$data[user]=$user` to $data['user']=$user`

Answer (score 0):

//Controller

```
$data['title'] = 'welcome to codeigniter';
$data['user'] = $this->db->get('users')->row();

$this->load->view('welcome', $data);
```

//View

```
<?=$title?>
<?=print_r($user)?>
```